# How to Move From Activity to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have to include three Fragment on my main Activity on click of Three Buttons on app bar. Now, Question is I want to go back from second activity to specific fragment on mainActivity I am using Intent but at start of app intent is null and get **nullpointer exception and app crash**.

Here is **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainBinding binding;

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
HomeFragment homeFrag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);

    //--------Set and Get Tool Bar-------//
    setSupportActionBar(binding.appbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    if(getIntent() !=null){
        String is = getIntent().getStringExtra("check");
        if(is.equals("1")){
            SearchFragment searchFrag = new SearchFragment();
            if(searchFrag != null){
                fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, searchFrag)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        }
    }else{
        homeFrag = new HomeFragment();
        if(homeFrag!=null) {
            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, homeFrag).commit();
        }
    }
}
public void MoveToSearchActivity(View view){
    SearchFragment searchFag = new SearchFragment();

    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,searchFag).commit();
}

public void MoveToHomeActivity(View view){
    if(homeFrag!=null) {
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, homeFrag).commit();
    }
}

public void MoveToAlertFrag(View view){
    AlertFragment alertFragment = new AlertFragment();

    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,alertFragment).commit();
}
```

And here is my **FilterActivity.java** from which I'm going back to fragment:

```
public class FilterActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private ActivityFilterBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);

    //--------------Get ToolBar-----------//
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(" ");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(FilterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            homeIntent.putExtra("check",1);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can move from second activit to firstactivity only..you have to manage on backpress which fragment you wnat to load

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what u want to say Plz elaborate more...

Comment: when you returning from second activity you will redirect to fristactivity. pass some value to notify first activity to open which fragment.this way only you cn return to fragmnet you want

Comment: I Think I'm using same thing with intent from second activity but first Activity is my mainActivity so when ap start It show Intent is null and nullpointer exception

Comment: use try catch for to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `MainActivity`,

```
// Toolbar code
...

int is = -1;
if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().hasExtra("check")) {
    is = getIntent().getIntExtra("check", -1);
}
switch (is) {
    case 1:
        // load SearchFragment
        break;
    case 2:
        // load MoveToAlertFrag
        break;
    default:
        // load HomeFragment
        break;
}
```

Comment: but how can I get frgment on button click event also

Comment: Which Button? It's not in the code given. Update the code.

Comment: I have define onClick property on my XML like MoveToAlert, MoveToSearch are call on button click

Comment: What is the issue with the click listeners?

Comment: Thanks It's works,,I'm just confuse,,,now It's all ok